# Making sure values are treated as Numeric when SQL Reporting 2008 renders a report as Excel

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

When I save a **SQL Report** in **Excel**, a column containing numbers is treated as text in the resulting `.xls` file. On each row the cell has a green right triangle and a yellow diamond exclamation mark saying "`The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe.`"

Can someone explain to me how to make it so the rendered report has no error for this column? My users wish to treat these cells as numeric; i.e. to perform calculations on these values, but they are text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by casting the field within the report.

```
=CDbl(Fields!mycolumn.Value)
```

**Edit**
The above example is the work around that I have always used for this issue, however, I just finished reading a post what the user noted that this was not needed, if you used the following code.

```
=IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value=0,Nothing,Fields!FieldName)
```

This seems to fix the issue and allow the use of FormatNumber.

The original post can be found [here](http://www.windows-tech.info/15/4233351fc1b50ac7.php).

Comment: So FormatNumber returns a string? How do you combine the power of FormatNumber to insert commas, place a decimal point at a decided level?

Comment: Also, on Excel, a cell may display as text: 60,000, but its value will be numeric: 60000. How may I cause that to happen in my SQL Reporting Definition File?